# Why I am getting empty array using storage::files in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

Hello guys I am using this code to get the list of files in my desktop using **Laravel**, I am new in this framework i didn't know why I am getting empty array even i have many files in my desktop?

```
$files = Storage::files('C:/Users/user123/Desktop');
 dd($files); //==> []
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to configure the `filesystems.php` file

by default, laravel is using the `./storage/app` folder

```php
    'disks' => [
        'local' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app'),
        ],
```

if you want to access your desktop files you need to do this

```php
    'disks' => [
        'local' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => 'C:/Users/user123/Desktop',
        ],
```

And then `$files = Storage::files();`

Another thing you can do is add another key for your filesystem

```php
    'disks' => [
        'custom' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => 'C:/Users/user123/Desktop',
        ],
```

And you can access your files like this `$files = Storage::disk('custom')->files();`